# Jenkins: Cannot run program "/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/jenkinsjob/taurus-venv/bin/bzt error=2

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, taurus, bzt

I've started to try this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin, but I am facing issues with my local jenkins (after Step 7). Looks like there is some issue with jenkins not being able to run bzt inside my virtual env.

```
Started by user user
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/jenkinsjob
Performance test: Checking global bzt installation...
[jenkinsjob] $ bzt --help
Performance test: You don't have global bzt installed on this Jenkins host. Installing it globally will speed up job. Run 'sudo pip install bzt' to install it.
Performance test: Checking virtualenv tool availability...
[jenkinsjob] $ /usr/local/bin/virtualenv --help
Performance test: Found virtualenv tool.
Performance test: Creating virtualev at 'taurus-venv'...
[jenkinsjob] $ /usr/local/bin/virtualenv --clear --system-site-packages taurus-venv
Performance test: Done creating virtualenv.
Performance test: Installing bzt into 'taurus-venv'
[jenkinsjob] $ /Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/jenkinsjob/taurus-venv/bin/pip install bzt
Performance test: bzt installed successfully.
Performance test: Checking installed bzt...
[jenkinsjob] $ /Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/jenkinsjob/taurus-venv/bin/bzt --help
Performance test: Failed to run bzt inside virtualenv.
Cannot run program "/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/jenkinsjob/taurus-venv/bin/bzt" (in directory "/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/jenkinsjob"): error=2, No such file or directoryBuild step 'Run Performance Test' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Has someone faced and fixed this issue? Could you help me on it, pls? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I set a different (from that one installed globally) version for bzt:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest Jenkins and Performance Plugin

[image]

Most probably [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) installation into [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) failed somewhere somehow, I would try the following:

1. Run `/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/jenkinsjob/taurus-venv/bin/pip install bzt` command in your Terminal and check the output
2. Run `/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/jenkinsjob/taurus-venv/bin/bzt --help` command and check the output

Also as Jenkins suggests you could install Taurus globally (for all users) running the following command:

```
sudo pip install bzt
```

and untick `Always use virtualenv` box in your build configuration:

[image]

In general you don't need Taurus to run a JMeter test and parse the results using Performance Plugin, you can [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode via normal Jenkins `Execute shell` build step](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins/) and then use `Publish performance test result report` post-build action to [generate the performance test reports and trend charts](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html).

Comment: hey, thank you! For some reason, I did the global installation of Taurus but jenkins does not find it somehow. As a solution, I set a different bzt version: like 1.15. And now it works. Not the best solution, but at least the pipeline now works.